# Media query on image

Tags: html, css, image, media-queries

I want to transform the main to `display:column` when `max-width:1220px`.
And I'm doing this

```
@media (max-width: 1220px) {
  .main {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
```

But when the width it's 1220px the image desapear.
What I am doing wrong?

This is the Code Pen link to be easier.

https://codepen.io/Rvssco/pen/LYzGYgV

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It has no dimensions - it's 100% of what? When things are in a column there's nothing to set the height. Try giving it some definite dimensions and you'll see it.

Comment: Try to give `div.right` some height and remove from `div.wrap` `height: 98vh;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image is disappearing because you have included the src of the image in CSS and not html, flex-direction is not able to detect the presence of image when changing direction and hence the image doesn't appear. You can see my code how I have done it.

```css
body {
  background-color: hsl(233, 47%, 7%);
  color: white;
}

h1,
p {
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Lexend Deca", sans-serif;
}

.desc {
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.75);
}

span {
  color: hsl(277, 64%, 61%);
}

.wrap {
  height: 98vh;
  width: 98vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  width: 85%;
  height: 80%uto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: hsl(244, 38%, 16%);
  flex-direction: row;
}

.left {
  padding: 5rem;
  padding-right: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 50%;
}

.text-container .title {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.desc {
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  word-spacing: 0.3rem;
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
}

.stats-desc {
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.6);
}

.stats-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 70%;
}

.right {
  width: 50%;
  /* background-image: url(./1.png); */
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.stats h1 {
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
}

.filter {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: hsla(277, 88%, 32%, 0.603);
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}



  .left {
    text-align: center;
  }


@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .main {
    /* display: block; */  /* Option 2*/
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    background-color:red;  /*Used for testing please remove*/
  }

  .left {
    text-align: center;
  }

/*Small modification in filer and right classes*/
  .filter {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: hsla(277, 88%, 32%, 0.603);
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}

  .right {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
      <div class="main" role="main" >
        <div class="left">
          <div class="text-container">
            <h1 class="title">
              Get <span>insights</span> that help your business grow.
            </h1>
          </div>
          <p class="desc">
            Discover the benefits of data analytics and make better decisions
            regarding revenue, customer experience, and overall efficiency.
          </p>
          <div class="stats-container">
            <div class="stats">
              <h1>10k+</h1>
              <p class="stats-desc">COMPANIES</p>
            </div>
            <div class="stats">
              <h1>314</h1>
              <p class="stats-desc">TEMPLATES</p>
            </div>
            <div class="stats">
              <h1>12M+</h1>
              <p class="stats-desc">QUERIES</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <img  class="filter" src= ./1.png>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I don't know the exact reason behind this, probably someone with higher depth knowledge would be able to comment.

If you still want to use the url from CSS you can still use it but instead changing the

```
flex-direction:column
```

do

```
diplay:block
```

Secondly, when you are using the media query, you need to redefine the classes used for image and its display(.filter and .right). Otherwise the changes will not be applied to them, this was kind of an obvious mistake which I observed.

Also you have re-defined media query twice and there is a mistake in CSS in using {} brackets.